# Google Docs editor like in any web language

Tags: editor, wysiwyg, google-docs

I have a project in where i need to write documents in a webeditor like the new googledocs,

I know that google docs doesnt support editing and saving the documents on my own server.

My question is :

There is any similar version of the new google docs payable or in any other licence that permits me to edit a document in an editor like the new google docs where can i save the content editable in my own db ,writen in any web programming language ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you mean to say you need exactly as Google Docs? - Like Uploading doc downloading doc kind of.

We can do it in jquery

Comment: not really , i need to make documents like  M$ word , that i will save in db and replace some variables with the client vars.
Like new google docs , i mean the pagination mode
 I have the standalone version of the old google docs , only the js.